# In which format should I save the file for printing on cellophane packaging?

Tags: print-design, packaging

I have a layout with transparent parts. How can I make sure that this parts will be stil transparent after printing? Which format should I use (currently it is .ai)?

Comment: Welcome along - Ask your printer! it depends on their systems and process.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the art: if it is all type and solid colors, probably AI/EPS/vector. Check with the print supplier.

Note that "normally," white is actually the paper color. For a "clear paper," you will need an actual white swatch.

Answer (score 0):

Almost *any* file destined for print these days should be saved as a **PDF/X-1a:2001** file regardless of the actual printing substrate.

However, **ask your print provider** to be certain.